# Can we use [DataMember] instead of [ProtoMember] while use protobuf in WCF?

Tags: wcf, serialization, protobuf-net

I've already a service working using the `DataContract` attributes. We would like to switch to the protobuf implementation, but if we have to change all the attributes, it would be a lot of hardwork.

Is it possible to NOT use the `ProtoMember` and `ProtoContract` and have ProtoBuf using the `DataMember` and `DataContract` attributes?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; protobuf-net is perfectly happy with `[DataContract]` / `[DataMember]` *as long as* it can still get valid numbers, which it does by looking for the `Order` property of `DataMemberAttribute`.

There is, however, a small problem... tools like `svcutil` *don't guarantee* the actual numbers - just the order. This can make it problematic to ensure that you have the **same** numbers of both sides. In addition, `svcutil` tends to start *at zero*, not one - and zero is not a valid field number for protobuf. If the numbers you get all turn out to be off-by-one, then you can tweak this by adding a `partial class` in a seperate file with a fixup, for example:

```
[ProtoContract(DataMemberOffset = 1)]
partial class Whatever { }
```

However, if the numbers are now *all over the place* (because they weren't sequential originally), they you might want to *either* use multiple `[ProtoPartialMember(...)]` attributes to tell it how to map each one (remembering that you can use `nameof` rather than hard-coding the member names):

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoPartialMember(1, nameof(SomeStringValue))]
[ProtoPartialMember(2, nameof(WhateverId))]
partial class Whatever { }
```

or just *share the original type definition*, which might be easier.

Comment: Great news. I'm not sure where in SVCUTIL, I would have to lookup for this kind of numbers. If I specify myself the `[DataMember(Order =1,...,x)]` in my classes, I should not run into this problem, right?

Comment: @J4N that depends... if that is the case for both ends of the communication, then great; the point, however, is that the actual numbers aren't part of the metadata exchange (mex) endpoint - so if you *just* use a service reference to consume that, it might start with `[DataMember(Order = 0)]` on the generated types

Comment: Okay, in our cases we do all "by hands", with our own channel factory and shared interfaces

Comment: @J4N that should work fine, then; I try to be comprehensive in these answers, because sadly how it works *is* contextual

Comment: And you're doing well, huge fan of your answers :) Helped me more times than I can count.